# sort string with delimiter as string in unix

Tags: shell, unix

I have some data in the following format::

```
Info-programNumber!/TvSource/11100001_233a_32c0/13130^Info-channelName!5 USA^Info-Duration!1575190^Info-programName!CSI: ab cd

Delimiter = Info-
```

I tried to sort the string based on the delimiter in ascending order. But none of my solutions are working.

Expected Result:

```
Info-channelName!5 USA^Info-Duration!1575190^Info-programName!CSI: ab cd^Info-programNumber!/TvSource/11100001_233a_32c0/13130
```

Is there any command that will allow me to do this or do i need to write an awk script to iterate over the string and sort it?

Comment: isn't the delimiter `^` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can be done in awk itself:

```
awk -F "^" '{OFS="^"; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) a[i]=$i} 
          END {n=asort(a, b); for(i=1; i<=n; i++) printf("%s%s", b[i], FS); print ""}' file
```

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 3):

Temporarily split the info into multiple lines so you can sort:

```
tr ^ \\n | sort | tr \\n ^
```

Note: if you have multiple entries, you have to write a loop, which processes it per line.. with huge datasets this is probably not a good idea (too slow), in which case pick a programming language.. but you were asking about the shell...